# Debugging a slow process

Tags: c++, debugging, time

I have a case where a bug takes more than an hour to manifest in debug mode (and still 20+ min in release mode). Does one know a debugging strategy which can help to reduce the waiting time until a breakpoint is reached in the area of the code which is suspected to contain the cause?

I have tried logging and prompting with a dialog to ask if the program should skip functions.

Ideally I would like to save the process state right before (what I believe is) the buggy section and then debug from that point.  I dont think this is possible.

I am using C++ on Windows with Visual Studio.  General solutions welcome.

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: I don't think a general solution is going to help resolve your specific issue.

Comment: @DanWilson that’s dubious.  Often general solutions to specific problems are the most useful sincs you can use them in many cases.  GDB is a “general solution” and clearly useful in many specific cases

Comment: @gnat how can I get the information I want? The link recommends reddit... do you think i should try that?

Comment: If you have a concrete question about using debugging tools in Visual Studio (e.g. “how can I set a breakpoint in VS?”) then Stack Overflow would be the appropriate address. See also: [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7253)

Comment: @amon i dont know a priori that the best method will involve any particular tool

Comment: I took the freedom and removed the buzzword "some debugging tips" out which gave some people here the wrong impression of a "too-broad-list-of-things" question. Please check if I still got your intentions right.

Comment: @amon: looks like a focussed, very on-topic question to me.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give a rough scetch of how the bug manifests / shows up, and if you can already limit the suspected source code section to a small area. Also, it would be nice if you tell us why the program takes so long and why you don't see any possibility to reproduce the bug in a way which takes less time.

Comment: @DocBrown the goal of this question is to learn to solve this bug and other bugs of a similar nature.  That's why I didn't post lots of precise info/post on SO.  That said, the bug manifests when the input to a certain function is really huge.  It takes a long time to generate that input.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash: posting an imprecise question increases the chance to get it closed as "too broad" on this site, as it has happened right now - too bad, I liked it.

Comment: If this is reopened, I'd answer my own question.  GDB supports "checkpoint" and "restart" which does exactly what I wanted 3 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible to save partial calculations? If so, you could save out the set of calculations that you know to be good, then reload them during future sessions and continue debugging from there.

If the tests are reproducible, like the 1,058th element of the 99th array of the frobaz always ends up wrong, you could put a watchpoint on that memory location and kick off your calculations. While it's plowing through the slow calculations, you can examine the code  manually to see if anything stands out. Eventually, it will stop when that element is modified. From there you can usually see where the bad input is coming from. (Probably a calculation with another bad element, so you get to try again with *that* element.)

Also, I highly  recommend running a static analyzer  on your code. It may well point out a problem  in the code  that  you hadn't  noticed and point out where  the error is coming from. Other  tools like valgrind, address sanitizer, etc. also help  in this regard.

**Edit** it occurs to me that you can “freeze the machine” in a way. If you have a virtual machine you can start your app and run the calculations up to the point where you want to start debugging. Save the VMs state. Do your debugging. When you want to return to that state simply restore the VM to where you saved it and begin debugging again. Of course if you change any code you’ll need to run the calcs again up to the point where you want to debug.

Comment: I cannot save partial calculations without putting in a lot of effort to serialize/load the data (unless there is an easy way to store data without changing address?).  The VM saved state is appealing.

Comment: +1, but note the problem with watchpoints is, they tend to slow down the execution time of a program in debug mode heavily.

Answer (score 1):

> > Does one know a debugging strategy which can help to reduce the waiting time until a breakpoint is reached in the area of the code which is suspected to contain the cause?

You can still profile debug functions. I wouldn't spend too much time on it, especially with a bug to fix, but if you have a glaring hotspot that takes 30% of the time or more in debug, and the solution is uber simple, then it might make a real productivity difference if devs are used to spending 30+ mins waiting on their debug builds to do something and even help you fix that bug sooner.

In my case we had a matrix/vector library one time which performed handsomely in release/production builds but we sprinkled assertions all over the place to make sure we weren't accessing arrays out of bounds and so forth in debug builds. I found hotspots there that were gross (like over 50% of time spent in such functions due to `asserts` all over the place), and ended up writing a unit test which made sure those functions behaved properly and made only those `asserts` applied when something like a `DEBUG_MATH_LIB` (I forgot what I called it, this was many years ago) was defined. That actually sped up running the software in debug mode substantially in ways where it when from complete torture to try to reproduce issues in the debugger to not too unbearable (debug was still maybe 20 times slower than release, but not 200 times slower).

If you are trying to reproduce a bug which results in faulty output (or crash or whatever) and it takes ages, then usually my number one technique if applicable when I used to deal with that a lot was to try to play with the content with a "binary search" mentality, and originally in a release build (I'm not running the debugger).

I might try loading one half of the content (after saving the whole content minus half of it deleted) and see if it glitches out. If it doesn't, then I try the other half and find that it glitches out. Then I divide that second half into quarters, and so forth, until it takes just seconds to load and reproduce the issue. After that the main issue that this problem takes so long to reproduce is solved, and the rest is the painful process of debugging it absent the bottleneck of waiting to reproduce it. It's been many years since I had to do that sort of thing (I've found designs which avoid this type of thing for the most part), but my hazy memories from the past recalls doing this stuff a lot.

Most of the time you shouldn't need to load 3 gigabytes of data to reproduce an issue. The first step to me is not figuring out the issue but making it faster to reproduce with that "binary search" mentality, halving the data until it's so small that it loads in an eye blink and causes the issue. Then I engage my  "debugging mode". That narrowing down of the data also tends to make it more obvious what part of it might be tripping up the software.

> > Ideally I would like to save the process state right before (what I believe is) the buggy section and then debug from that point. I dont think this is possible.

On windows at least, you can right click on any running process and output a dump file.
[image]

You can then open the resulting `.DMP` file in, say, Visual Studio and jump right into debugging it.

Unfortunately that doesn't allow resuming the process to my knowledge and letting it finish (making dumps usually only useful to me when the software crashes). However, it can be a way to sort of save a stack dump and inspect things and be able to come back and look at them some more.